# How do I export recordings in Mythbuntu?

Tags: mythtv

I would like to copy all recordings of a certain show to a folder so I can transfer them to another computer and watch them "offline". MythTV stores all recordings in a single folder in files titled "2609_20111111093000.nuv" which makes finding all the episodes I want a daunting task.

I tried using MythArchive but it seemingly oriented at burning files to DVDs. In addition, my MythTV crashes when I try to use MythArchive.

I'm not particularly concerned with converting/recompressing files, just copying them would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I found, and it's nearly perfect:

- there's a standard MythTV script called [mythlink.pl](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Mythlink.pl), which is able to create human-readable links to all recording files:

  ```
  mythlink.pl --link /mnt/pretty --format '%T/%T%-%S'
  ```
- after the script created the links, I can use `cp --dereference` or, even better, Midnight Commander, to copy any files I want wherever I want with nice human-readable names.

Comment: accepting my own answer since that's what I ended up using. mythvfs was ok-ish too but on my machine it was just too sluggish.

Answer (score 1):

[mythnuv2mkv](http://web.aanet.com.au/auric/?q=node/6) allows you to convert any `.nuv` to other standard formats with the ability to look in imdb for titles and other information about the files.

I have not personally used it but it sounds very easy to use and the necessary tools (other than the script) are available for Ubuntu:

- `mythtranscode` - mythtv-transcode-utils (multiverse)
- `perl` - perl (main)
- `mplayer` - mplayer (multiverse or non-free(medibuntu))
- `mencoder` - mencoder (multiverse or non-free(medibuntu))
- `wget` - wget (main)
- `ImageMagick` - imagemagick (main)
- `bc` - bc (main)

Give it a go and drop a comment if it does not do what you are looking for.

Comment: This is an interesting script which will be useful after I figure out which episodes I want to convert - and it even has an option to copy a file to another folder. And even an option to find episodes by title. Which would be ideal. BUT: when using --findtitle option, it just prints the list of episodes and exits, no other options have any effect. So I can't use it to copy all episodes with a certain title.

Comment: It should allow to just convert all of them (creating new files with titles) and after you will be able to sort them out. I know it sounds a bit tedious but should do the job.

Comment: Note that I don't want to convert them, I just want to copy *some of them*. Converting a few terabytes of files is going to take... I don't know... weeks? Then it'll move them all to MythVideo, which I don't want, and it'll disable auto-expiry, and... just to many side-effects. But thanks for suggesting the script, I'm going to use it after I copied the files I need out of mythtv.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to show filenames in a human-readable format, without reconverting or copying them, you can get it and saving disk-space using the virtual filesystem [MythVFS](http://outflux.net/software/pkgs/mythtvfs-fuse/) which can be installed via

```
sudo apt-get install mythtvfs
```

Just "mount" a virtual filesystem by configuring it in `/etc/fstab` and you'll see all your recording files with title, date, channel number or whatever you like in the filename.

Here's an example on how I mount it via `fstab`:

```
mythtvfs#/media/mythtv /media/VFS/mythtv fuse user,noauto,allow_other,uid=mythtv,gid=mythtv,host=localhost,format=%T-%S-(@%c-%s)_%f,date_format=%Y-%m-%d,datetime_format=%Y-%m-%d-h%H:%M 0 0
```

where:
`/media/mythtv` is my recording directory
`/media/VFS/mythtv` is my MythTv VFS mountpoint
`mythtv` is my MythTv's user (ad group) id

Comment: That's an interesting option, thanks. Do you know if it's possible to make it to create "subfolders" for each show with all episodes inside that subfolder?

Comment: I think this could be realized by mounting a specific type of recordings in its own directory. Writing a shell script that query the database and creates different mountpoints depending on the serie's title could make the trick, but I didn't try and I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Mythexport](http://www.mythbuntu.org/wiki/MythExport)?

I am not sure if it is still being worked on, as I have had a few issues with it. But I believe it would be what you are looking for.

With it you can schedule to have recordings transcoded to configurable encoding and it will move the export to a folder you configure. It also names the files to a human readable format.